# How does update management works for virtual machines in Azure?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, scheduled-task, update

We defined the execution's time of the update management with a runbook for 6 hours.

But I would like to know : Does update management work asynchronously (every virtual machines are getting updated at the same time)?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, update management will look to update all machines at the same time.